# Does Jena support enforcing OWL constraints during a SPARQL Update query?

Tags: sparql, jena, jena-rules

I'm trying to figure out if Jena (or any other SPARQL Update server) will enforce ontological constraints.  For example, I want to enforce that only entities which have type x are allowed to have property y and the value of the property must have type z.  I think this is what OWL can provide, but I'm not sure.  Also, specifically, will Jena ensure that if I try to write a SPARQL Update query which does not follow these rules, that update will fail to insert and an error will be returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *For example, I want to enforce that only entities which have type x are allowed to have property y and the value of the property must have type z. I think this is what OWL can provide, but I'm not sure.*

What you're asking for is *not* what OWL provides. In OWL, you can say that:

propertyY rdfs:domain typeX
    propertyY rdfs:domain typeZ

but this *does not* mean (at least, in the way that you're expecting), that only things of type X can have values for propertyY, and that the values must be of type Z.  What it means is that whenever you see an assertion that uses propertyY, like

a propertyY b

an OWL reasoner can *infer* that

a rdf:type typeX
    b rdf:type typeZ

The only time those inferences will be any kind of "constraint violation" is if you have some other way of inferring that **a** *cannot* be of type X, or that **b** *cannot* be of type Z.  Then an OWL reasoner would recognize the inconsistency.

> *I'm trying to figure out if Jena (or any other SPARQL Update server) will enforce ontological constraints. … Also, specifically, will Jena ensure that if I try to write a SPARQL Update query which does not follow these rules, that update will fail to insert and an error will be returned?*

I don't know whether Jena supports something like this out of the box, but you probably could probably either:

1. Use an OntModel with a reasoner attached, and run your SPARQL updates against that graph.  Then, you can *query* the graph and see whether any inconsistency is found.  How this would be done would depend on how the reasoner signals inconsistencies.  This might not all that hard, but remember that Jena is really RDF-based and for full OWL reasoning, you'll need another reasoner that integrates with Jena (e.g., Pellet, but there are others, too, I think).
2. Alternatively, you might use a store that has reasoning built in, and probably has this kind of functionality already.  I think that Stardog has some of these features.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand about OWL is [property restriction](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#Restriction):

> A **property restriction** is a special kind of class description. It describes an anonymous class, namely a class of all individuals that satisfy the restriction. OWL distinguishes two kinds of property restrictions: value constraints and cardinality constraints.
>
> A **value constraint** puts constraints on the range of the property when applied to this particular class description.
>
> A **cardinality constraint** puts constraints on the number of values a property can take, in the context of this particular class description.

Based on the description of your problem, you need to use a value constraint. These value constraints exists: some (`someValuesFrom`), only (`allValuesFrom`), and exactly (`hasValue`).

For example:

```
Class: Woman subClassOf: hasGender only Female
Class: Mother subClassOf: hasChild some Child
Class: Employee subClassOf: hasEmployeeID exaclty 1 ID
```

So depending on the restrictions on the individuals that you have defined, these individuals can be classified by the reasoner under the right class, which will be their type. The systems generally won't prevent you from entering false information, but the concept will either be declared unsatifiable or inconsistent. In the case of entering an individual that is incompatible with the constants in the ontology, the ontology becomes inconsistent (everything goes wrong) then you can retract the last fact I suppose. I am not sure about Jena, but OWL-API lets you temporarily add a concept to the ontology manager, and then you can check the consistency of the ontology. Normally when this check goes wrong, you can remove the last unsaved change to the ontology manger (via the change listener), and if everything is correct, you can save the changes in the ontology manager.